# Undefined control sequence when inserting tikzpicture in beamer

Tags: tikz-pgf, beamer

I'm new to both beamer and tikz, after looking at many examples I was able to create the tikz picture that I want in a regular latex article. I wanted to reuse the same image in beamer but when I do so I get an undefined control sequence error.

I've found the cause to be the `&` I use to draw a matrix, if I escape it with a `\` then latex stops complaining, however, this does not give the desired picture. Below is the tikz picture I expect.
An MWE with the problem follows, it doesn't try to recreate the image in its entirety. I don't think all the code for the image is necessary right now as that might clutter the MWE. However, I'm happy to provide it if necessary. Thanks.

[image]

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{trees, matrix}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows.meta}

\tikzset{
    every matrix/.style={
        inner sep=-\pgflinewidth,
        matrix of math nodes,
        column sep=-\pgflinewidth,
        nodes={
            draw=black,
            font=\color{black},
            minimum size=.75cm,
            anchor=center
        }
    }
}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}

\begin{tikzpicture}
    \tikzstyle{root} = [circle,draw=black, thick]
    \node[root] (r0) at (0,2){root};
    \matrix (l0) at (0,0) {a & ... & z\\};
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

Comment: You need to add to `frame` option `fragile`: `\begin{frame}[fragile]`.

Comment: @Zarko That worked! Thanks, if you post this as an answer I'll happily accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to add to `frame` option `fragile`:

```
\documentclass{beamer}
%\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{matrix}

\tikzset{
    every matrix/.style={
        inner sep=-\pgflinewidth,
        matrix of math nodes,
        column sep=-\pgflinewidth,
        nodes={draw,
               minimum size=.75cm,
               anchor=center}
    }
}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}[fragile]  % <----

\begin{tikzpicture}
    \tikzstyle{root} = [circle,draw=black, thick]
    \node[root] (r0) at (0,2){root};
    \matrix (l0) at (0,0) {a & ... & z\\};
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

(your MWE doesn't reproduce in question showed image)

[image]

Comment: Yeah, it doesn't produce the same image. It is the image I'm intending to draw. I suppose it is unnecessary  now that I think about it :-)